# gcloud docker push failing "unable to ping registry endpoint https://gcr.io/v0/"

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, docker-registry

I am trying to set-up Google Container Engine, I am trying to push my first Docker Container into GCE Repository, however I am getting following errors:

```
oash-3.2$ gcloud docker push gcr.io/prlr-dev-01/centos-7-systemd --verbosity inf 
INFO: Refreshing access_token
INFO: Refreshing access_token
INFO: Refreshing access_token
INFO: Refreshing access_token
INFO: Refreshing access_token
INFO: Refreshing access_token
INFO: Refreshing access_token
The push refers to a repository [gcr.io/prlr-dev-01/centos-7-systemd]
unable to ping registry endpoint https://gcr.io/v0/
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://gcr.io/v2/: dial tcp:     lookup gcr.io on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp     10.0.2.15:56392->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout
v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://gcr.io/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup gcr.io on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:35899->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout
bash-3.2$
```

My Docker version is:

```
bash-3.2$ docker --version
Docker version 1.10.2, build c3959b1
bash-3.2$
```

And my "curl ping" works just fine:

```
bash-3.2$ curl https://gcr.io/v1/_ping -n
truebash-3.2$
```

I got no idea where does 10.0.2.15 and 10.0.2.3 come from as I am using 192.168.1.0/24 segment on my office WiFi connection and 10.0.0.0/24 in GCE.

Do you have any clue what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you using docker-machine or boot2docker (possibly on a laptop)? If so, have you tried reseting your instance? I have seen a number of folks run into problems with their docker-machine losing the ability to talk to the internet when hopping networks (e.g. home <-> work).

Comment: restarting docker-machine solve this issue for me

Comment: GCR [troubleshooting page](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/troubleshooting) also recommends restarting boot2docker. For me the same trick worked for docker-machine on mac

Comment: I can see you have resolved this issue, can you post your solution as answer which will help other users with the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments from other users, restarting docker has resolved the issue. The [GCR troubleshooting guide](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/troubleshooting) also has useful debugging information.